# Check if array variable has mor than x values?

Tags: twig

I'm using twig and want to check if the given variable xyz has more than x entries. How is that possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the length filter is the way to go.

```
{% if xyz | length > x %}
   {% do something %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think xyz|length will work.

Comment: You "answered" your own question in a speculative manner without a working example?